# Upload images from camera or gallery to facebook wall code android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am new to facebook android sdk.i want to upload images from camera or gallery through application to facebook wall . i have wriiten code like this but its not working.Please help me any help will be appreciated.
I have given this permission :

`private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"user_photos","publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access","photo_upload"};`

my posting code is like this:

```
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFbRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

    Bundle params = new Bundle();


    params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
    params.putByteArray("picture", photoId);

    mAsyncFbRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new WallPostListener());
```

But its not working for me.Please help me

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: no..i am not getting any error.but it is not posting in my wall

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [LINK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/)

it may helps you.

and the other way is

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();

String attachment="{\"name\":\""+Title+"\"," +
                "\"href\":\"Title Link.\"," +
                "\"caption\":\""+Fb Caption Message+"\",\"description\":" +
                "\""+ImageDescription+"\",\"media\":" +
                "[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":" +
                "\""+Image_url+"\"," +
                "\"Linkable URL Path\":" +
                ".\"}}}";

params.putString("attachment",attachment.toString());
```

i am using this way in one of my app.